# UnBlock propertyAttr in Jena RDF/XML

Tags: rdf, jena

I am trying to figure out how to unblock the propertyAttr while writing RDF/XML with Jena.
As the documentation says, “By default, rule propertyAttr is blocked.”  I have tried, however I can't get it blocked in RDF/XML-ABBREV mode.

```java
RDFWriter w = m.getWriter("RDF/XML-ABBREV");
w.setProperty("tab", "2");
w.setProperty("blockRules",  "propertyAttr");
w.write(m, System.out, "");
```

This is my desired output, `eg:value="v"` is set as an attribute:

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:eg="http://example.org/"
         xml:base="http://example.org/dir/file">
  <rdf:Description rdf:ID="frag" eg:value="v" />
</rdf:RDF>
```

This is my real output:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://example.org/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/dir/filefrag">
    <j.0:value>v</j.0:value>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted,

```java
w.setProperty("blockRules",  "propertyAttr");
```

does not unblock the `"propertyAttr"` rule.  On the contrary, it *blocks* it.  From [the documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdfxml_howto.html)

> `blockRules`: A list of Resource or a String being a comma separated list of fragment IDs from http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar indicating grammar rules that will not be used. Rules that can be blocked are: …
>
> - propertyAttr (RDFSyntax.propertyAttr)

so your code is actually *preventing* the writer from using the `propertyAttr` rule.

The following code prints your model after doing

```java
writer.setProperty( "blockRules", "" );
```

and produces the output (which is your desired output):

```xml
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/dir/file#frag"
     j.0:value="v"/>
```

Here's the full code that I used.  It prints the model twice, actually.  The first time `"blockRules"` is set to `"propertyAttr"`, and the second time it is set to `""`.

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFWriter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;

public class PropertyWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        Resource frag = model.createResource( "http://example.org/dir/file#frag" );
        Property value = model.createProperty( "http://example.org/value" );
        frag.addProperty( value, "v" );
        
        RDFWriter writer = model.getWriter( "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
        
        writer.setProperty( "blockRules", "propertyAttr" );
        writer.write( model, System.out, null );
        
        writer.setProperty( "blockRules",  "" );
        writer.write( model, System.out, null );
    }
}
```

Here's the output (the model is printed twice, and the second time is in the format that you want):

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://example.org/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/dir/file#frag">
    <j.0:value>v</j.0:value>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://example.org/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/dir/file#frag"
     j.0:value="v"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```